# How can I using BrowserRouter instead of HashRouter in react-router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, server-side-rendering

```
const routes = [
    { component: Root,
        routes: [
            { path: '/',
                exact: true,
                component: Home
            },
            { path: '/child/:id',
                component: Child,
                routes: [
                    { path: '/child/:id/grand-child',
                        component: GrandChild
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

`routes.config.js` export routes object using in `renderRoutes` method which is exported by `react-router-config`

when I start the app and access the url `localhost:3000` the Home component will be rendered .

If access `localhost:3000/child` the request is `404`.

If  access `localhost:3000/#/child` but it render `Home` component instead of `Child` component

In the development mode I know can add devServer:{historyApiFallback:true}, but should I do in the production mode ?

If using `HashRouter` it works well.

So how can I using the BrowserRouter?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Step 1: Wrap your <App /> inside <BrowserRouter />

Step 2: <Router path="/child" component={Child} />

Step 3: Point this router using <Link to="/CHILD>Child</Link>"
```

Comment: The problem is that i have localhost:3000 for node and localhost:5000 for flask. This works completely fine in the local environment. But for my dev env my app url is https://application.name.com and my flask url is https://application.name.com so it loads fine when the link component is clicked but it fails when i refresh it as it thinks this is a flask end point (server side routing)